# How to move cells in a specific pattern

Tags: excel, vba

This is my debut post here in Stack Overflow, hope I don't cross any rule.

Basically, I'm good in excel logic, tough I'm lacking some knowledge about it's functions and I have 0 knowledge about VBA.
My goal is to consolidate a bunch of questionnaires made with employees of one of our clients. I used Power Query to  get them all in the same sheet, though I need to consolidate some stuff.

I have 1 column I need to tabulate (values from 1 to 5 --> Answers from each question), and  2 Columns I need to concatenate for all questionnaires, usually I receive this questionnaires, in the same sheet, side by side, so I just use "&" to consolidate it all with something to separate it all like "C1&"/"&D1&"/"...".
Now i have a LARGE sum of questionnaires which I need to:

1. Delete the first 11 rows of each questionnaire (they are headers and generic info);
2. For each new questionnaire I need to "Cut" the value column( which is F) and paste it in the column next to the first questionnaire , and so on...
3. Do the same thing for both of the other 2 columns I need to concatenate.

Any ideas how to this in the Fastest way? if possible, I want to automatize it?

EDIT:

This is one questionnaire , I have to consolidate **29** of it in one sheet:
[image]

I need not to repeat columns A-D, though, I want column F, G and H to be side by side like this:
[image]

Made this consolidation manually. (Open questionnaire , Cut column F, insert column on consolidate sheet, cut column G...)

Comment: PowerQuery .... put all files in same folder then `Data > Get Data > From Folder`.  Then transform your file imports to suit.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, done that. That's why i need to do step 1, 2 e 3. in order to consolidate it as it is

Comment: Once you've selected the folder to import from it will give you a list of file details in that folder.  Click the `Transform Data` button and expand the Content.  You'll end up with all files stuck together, including the 11 rows you want to remove, etc.  Select the `Transform Sample File` query, update that so it looks correct (removed rows, etc) and run your query.  Not sure what _paste it in the column next to the first questionary_ means, so can't really help with that.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook 
"paste it in the column next to the first questionary" means that i want to transfer all the info to the next column after the last one in questionary one.   Meaning i want to consolidate all info in the horizontal way, not vertical

to consolidade everything in the vertical, i already have a script, i just need to name all sheets "table 1, 2, 3..."

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a sample of data please.  A picture says a thousand words and _"i want to consolidate all info in the horizontal way, not vertical to consolidade everything in the vertical"_ isn't saying anything to me.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook added up the images. I Tried power query, but i'm not expert in it yet, it only put one sheet bellow the other, verticaly

Comment: Aside:  It looks like you should learn about the TEXTJOIN function, if you have it in your version of Excel.

Comment: Can you clarify where the different columns F,G,H are pasted to? Do they go to separate sheets?

Comment: @Joffan I didn't know textjoin, might update the formula
 About F, G & H columns... This time i have 29 questionnaries, wich are the same. I  use Column F to measure indicator values. Column G is where i collect everything that is "aggravating" the indicator, and in column H i collect everything that is "mitigating" the indicator.
What i need to do? - have all questionnaries side by side, so i can use textjoin to consolidate column G & H. 
If possible, i'd like to have all columns "F" side by side, all columns "G" together, and same for "H"

Comment: @Jurebaao I think TEXTJOIN would make a huge simplification to your monster formula in the second image, since the second parameter is a boolean (TRUE/FALSE) that directs whether to skip empty cells.